# Install wordpress container under wwwroot folder

Tags: wordpress, azure, docker, containers

I build a docker image in my azure container registry based in this configuration :

- [DockerFile](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/multicontainerwordpress/blob/master/Dockerfile)
- [Docker-entrypoint.sh](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/multicontainerwordpress/blob/master/docker-entrypoint.sh)

It builds , but when I check my site via FTP :

- I get no files under home/site/wwwroot

[image]
* I need to know why I get this page even I have no files under the folder wwwroot

[image]

Any ideas to resolve this issue ?

Thanks,

**Update**

When I use the dockerhub container :

[image]

I can get files under site/wwwroot of the appservice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your issue, I think what you need is to use the persistent storage for Azure Web App when you set the volumes in the compose file like this:

```
services:
   wordpress:
     image: microsoft/multicontainerwordpress
     volumes:
      - ${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME}/site/wwwroot:/var/www/html
     ports:
       - "8000:80"
     restart: always
```

Then you need to set the environment variable `WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE` as `true` in app settings. Then you will see the files in the path /home/site/wwwroot like below, no matter in the FTPS or KUDU.

In KUDU:

[image]

appsettings:

[image]

In FTP:

[image]

For more details, see [Add persistent storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/tutorial-multi-container-app#add-persistent-storage).

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress is running from `/var/www/html`, not from the path you are checking.

Update - at first I didn't quite understand from where you get site/wwwroot path. Now I realised that this is the IIS structure for appservice applications on Azure.

However this storage you're checking is from the appservice runtime, not from the container. If you run app from container, this folder structure is unused and checking ftp for data from container will not work.

Comment: thanks for your reply. So how can I visualize the data from container ? Plz see my update